# How to test higher-dimensional solutions to ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If you have a linear ODE, like simply $y'(t)=y(t)$, one method is to assume a solution of the form $e^{ \lambda t}$, find that the characteristic equations is not dependent on $t$ and thus to solve for $ \lambda$.

However, what if you have a system like $$\mathbf{x'} =  \begin{bmatrix} x'(t) \\ y'(t) \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y(t) \\ x(t) \\ \end{bmatrix}?$$

Now there is a more general solution as the normalized exponential of the Jordan-form of the matrix, but what if you have a non-trivial system but still want to try a substitution in this higher dimensional case? What would you need to do differently to have the same effect analogous to the one-dimensional case?

In this example, would I say "take $ \textbf{x}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_y} \\ e^{\lambda_x} \\ \end{bmatrix}...$"?

Answer (score 2):

If your equation is linear, say, $\mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{A\,x}(t)$ for some constant matrix $\mathbf{A}$, then the general solution takes the form $\mathbf{x}(t)=\exp(\mathbf{A}t)\,\mathbf{x}(0)$, where $$\exp(\mathbf{M}):=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{r!}\,\mathbf{M}^r$$ for every square matrix $\mathbf{M}$ (here $\mathbf{M}^0$ is defined to be the identity matrix).  In your case, you can write $\mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{x}(t)$ with $$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},$$  so that $$\exp(\mathbf{A}t)=\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(t)&\sinh(t)\\\sinh(t)&\cosh(t)\end{bmatrix}.$$
You can actually see that, in this case, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are linear combinations of $\exp(+t)$ and $\exp(-t)$.  This is because $+1$ and $-1$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

In order to find the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$, you can assume that you have a nonzero solution $\mathbf{x}(t)=\exp(\lambda t)\,\mathbf{x}(0)$ for some $\lambda$.  It will turn out that $\lambda$ has to be a root of the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$.  In your particular example, you can show by plugging in $x(t)=\exp(\lambda t)\,x_0$ and $y(t)=\exp(\lambda t)\,y_0$ that $\lambda^2-1=0$, and $\lambda^2-1$ is precisely the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ in this example.

Even when $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix function $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}(t)$, you can still write
$$\mathbf{x}(t)=\exp\left(\int_0^t\,\mathbf{A}(s)\,\text{d}s\right)\,\mathbf{x}(0).$$
In non-linear cases, unless you are specific about what types of equations you are looking at, I think the question is too broad.

Comment: Well I specifically asked about non-linear cases. This example is simply a precursor to non-linear cases. If it works for a linear case, then a similar technique might work for some non-linear cases. In general, you can't just exponentiate a matrix and expect to solve the system. However, you should in general be able to simply ****test**** a solution no matter what kind of crazy non-linear system you have.

Comment: Do you want to discuss something like $\mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{F}\big(\mathbf{x}(t),t\big)$ for some vector function $\mathbf{F}$?  That is too broad, and even in the $1$-dimensional situation, there is no method that solves all cases.

Comment: I am getting the impression you are not taking the time to read what I am saying. I never said there was a general method to solve all cases. For the third time, I am asking about ****testing**** solutions. In general, you are able to ****test**** solutions. They may work, they may not, but you *can* ****test**** them.

Comment: Even in $1$-dimensional case, there is no known general algorithm to construct a test solution for a nonlinear equation (except for making random guesses from an uncountable-dimensional space of differentiable functions).  Only in particular cases do we have some ideas what the solutions should look like.  I am not sure what you are trying to ask anymore.  And maybe you haven't read all I wrote, but then I am not sure without more clarification from you what you actually want.  And isn't testing a solution just "plugging in" to see if it works?

Comment: To make a good guess requires that you know what kind of equations you are dealing with.  Otherwise, the chance of succeeding is simply $0$.  So far, you are not providing more information, and becoming increasingly rude.

Comment: I provided plenty of information, you are choosing to willfully ignore what I am asking. Nowhere at all did I ask anyone for a generalized solution to any linear ODE, I asked how to implement a guess in general, using one specific type of linear ODE as an example upon which one can show it. Your information on the generalized solution is therefore negligible. What you should have done is showed whether and how the test in the post can be implemented to formulate a solution to that specific system.

Comment: I have said once, and will say it one last time.  Apart from "random guesses," there are no known general ways to make "good, reasonable, educated" guesses for solutions to a general nonlinear equation.  You have to know some extra information about your equation.  For example, is it a Cauchy-Euler equation?  If so, there is a good substitution you can make to trivialize the equation.

Comment: I'm not asking you to formulate a good guess for any system. I'm the one formulating the guesses. As I will say for the fifth time now, I am only asking how to implement such a guess (after it has been formulated). No one ask asking you to magically solve any differential equation.

Comment: If you have a guess, all you do is to plug in to see if it works, no?  What more do you want to do?  In fact, what else can you do to see whether your guess works?

Comment: I did not downvote your question by the way.  But I can see why it is being downvoted.